# Checking for string in a combobox list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I need to program my combobox in such a way that  when checkbox1 is clicked, "1" will be added into the combobox list, and if checkbox1 is unchecked, "1" will be removed from the list. Similarly for other checkboxes (eg. checkbox2, checkbox3, etc).

I can add "1" to the list, but am not sure what code should be used for checking and removing. This is how I have coded it:

```
void MyProject::OnBnClickedCheckBox1()
{
    if( //ComboBox list does not have "1")
    {
        CComboBox *pComboboxCam1 = (CComboBox *)(GetDlgItem(IDC_Cam1Combo));
        pComboboxCam1 = (CComboBox *)(GetDlgItem(IDC_Cam1Combo));
        pComboboxCam1->AddString(_T("1"));  
    }
    else
        //Remove "1" from list
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`CComboBox::FindString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=vs-2019#findstring) or [`CComboBox::FindStringExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=vs-2019#findstringexact) method to find the index of the string, then use the [`CComboBox::DeleteString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=vs-2019#deletestring) method to remove it.

For example:

```cpp
void MyProject::OnBnClickedCheckBox1()
{
    CButton *pCheckboxCam1 = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_Cam1Check);

    CComboBox *pComboboxCam1 = (CComboBox *) GetDlgItem(IDC_Cam1Combo);
    int index = pComboboxCam1->FindString(-1, _T("1"));

    if (pCheckboxCam1->GetCheck() == BST_CHECKED)
    {
        if (index < 0)
            pComboboxCam1->AddString(_T("1"));
    }
    else
    {
        if (index >= 0)
            pComboboxCam1->DeleteString(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: May i ask what the "-1" in "FindString(-1, _T("1"))" does?

Comment: @m170115 per the documentation I linked to in my answer: "*`nStartAfter` Contains the zero-based index of the item before the first item to be searched. When the search reaches the bottom of the list box, it continues from the top of the list box back to the item specified by `nStartAfter`. **If -1, the entire list box is searched from the beginning**.*"

Answer (score 0):

You should either use the FindString function or the FindStringExact function. They search for the string in the combobox and return either the index, if the value is greater than or equal to 0, or CB_ERR is the search was unsuccessful.

```
CComboBox *pComboboxCam1 = (CComboBox *)(GetDlgItem(IDC_Cam1Combo));
 if( pComboboxCam1->FindStringExact(0,_T("1")) == CB_ERR) // first parameter is the indextStart, second one is the string
    {
    //String not found
    pComboboxCam1 = (CComboBox *)(GetDlgItem(IDC_Cam1Combo));
    pComboboxCam1->AddString(_T("1"));  
    }
    else
    //String found
```